# Addressable Directory and Addressable Loading Logic

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

I have a question about how Addressables deal with Addressable directories I hope you could help me with.

Let's say I have bunch of assets (prefabs or sprites) inside a directory (let's call it "mydirectory") which I want to load dynamically at runtime using Addressables; Instead of marking each of the assets as Addressable, I make the containing directory (i.e. "mydirectory") as addressable. Loading assets using Addressables API works without any problems this way.

The question however is: When I load one specific asset from the assets in "mydirectory" using `Addressables.LoadAssetAsync(".../mydirectory/asset1")`, will other addressable assets in the directory gets loaded in the memory because they are in the same directory and under the same addressable entry in the addressable group? Or Addressables deal with each asset in that directory as if they are a separate entry in the addressable group?

Comment: When in doubt, do some profiling.

Comment: Memory profiler to be exact.